# How to connect multiple m-n relationship records

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
model School {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  teachers Teacher[]
  students Student[]
}

model Teacher {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  schools   School[]
  students  Student[]
}

model Student {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  teacherId Int
  teacher   Teacher @relation(fields: [teacherId], references: [id])
  schoolId  Int
  school    School  @relation(fields: [schoolId], references: [id])
}
```

I want to create in a single call a school, with teacher and student. This is my attempt:

```
prisma.school.create({
    data: {
        name: "Best",
        teachers: {
            create: {
                id: 2,
                firstName: "Charles",
                lastName: "Wise",
                students: {
                    create: {
                        firstName: "Pauline",
                        lastName: "Jenkins",
                        school: {
                            connect: {
                                id: -1 // How to reference a school that is being created?
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to pass a school's id when creating a student.

I know that I can do it in two calls by first creating a school with a teacher and then creating a student with that just created school and teacher:

```
const school = await prisma.school.create({
    data: {
        name: "Best",
        teachers: {
            create: {
                id: 2,
                firstName: "Charles",
                lastName: "Wise",
            }
        }
    },
    include: {
        teachers: true,
    }
});
await prisma.student.create({
    data: {
        firstName: "Pauline",
        lastName: "Jenkins",
        school: {
            connect: {
                id: school.id
            }
        },
        teacher: {
            connect: {
                id: school.teachers[0].id
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But that looks kind of weird and error prone.

Is there a way to rewrite it to a single call?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet to either connect to if a record exists or create on the go when it is not there.

```
prisma.teachers.create({
        data: {
            id: 2,
            firstName: 'Charles',
            lastName: 'Wise',
            students: {
                create: {
                    firstName: 'Pauline',
                    lastName: 'Jenkins',
                },
            },
            school: {
                connectOrCreate: {
                    where: {
                        name: 'best',
                    },
                    create: {
                        name: 'best',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });
```